# I would like to locate / validate generation my php error log on redhat fedora 20 linux

Tags: php, linux

I am working with lampserver to generate an application and I am getting a 'white screen'.

I have looked through stackoverflow for help and most posts suggest looking at the php.log file.

I looked in php.ini and my error_log was blank and display_errors = On.

Having read on this site I set error_log = /var/log/php-scripts.log and display_errors = Off,

I ran m application and the /var/log/php-scripts.log was not even created the application was launched and the file containing my php code was launched but my php code did not do anything and the php-scripts.log still did not exist.

I created php-scripts.log and set permissions to -rw-rw-rw- and ran again nothing was written to the file.

Can anybody help me to generate the log file and 
gain some valuable information?

Hi arkasha yes this is apache running on localhost on my linux laptop, as I made changes I restarted the laptop, I have deleted the file I created (it was still empty) ran my app again and still didn't get a log file.

Hi jonnu yes it is apache, I found an error_log file and an access_log file.
The last entry in the error_log file is timed at 11:51:12 and I have run my app often since then.
The last 4 lines:-
[Mon Apr 21 11:51:03.216320 2014] [core:notice] [pid 829] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Mon Apr 21 11:51:08.863310 2014] [suexec:notice] [pid 829] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Mon Apr 21 11:51:08.948152 2014] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 829] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Apr 21 11:51:08.951835 2014] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 829] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Mon Apr 21 11:51:12.667742 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 829] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (Fedora) PHP/5.5.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Apr 21 11:51:12.667869 2014] [core:notice] [pid 829] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'

There is also an access.log file that has more recent entries:-

127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2014:11:49:19 +0100] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.6 (Fedora) PHP/5.5.7 (internal dummy connection)"
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2014:11:49:20 +0100] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.6 (Fedora) PHP/5.5.7 (internal dummy connection)"
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2014:11:49:19 +0100] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.6 (Fedora) PHP/5.5.7 (internal dummy connection)"
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2014:11:49:20 +0100] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.6 (Fedora) PHP/5.5.7 (internal dummy connection)"
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2014:11:56:08 +0100] "GET /newarch/index.php/lgncntrl/ HTTP/1.1" 200 65602 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2014:17:12:47 +0100] "GET /newarch/index.php/lgncntrl/ HTTP/1.1" 200 65837 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2014:17:13:12 +0100] "GET /newarch/index.php/lgncntrl/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 65650 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2014:17:14:30 +0100] "GET /newarch/index.php/lgncntrl/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 65650 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2014:17:15:08 +0100] "GET /newarch/index.php/lgncntrl/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 65885 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2014:17:32:43 +0100] "GET /newarch/index.php/lgncntrl/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 65650 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0"

newarch/index.php/lgncntrl/login/ is my application

Comment: If this is a web application, then did you restart your http server after those changes to the configuration file? You have to reload it to have the changes read in. Typically (depending on your setup) it is the http server you have to restart, so apache or similar. You do _not_ have to generate that file manually (actually you should not), it will be created automatically by the server.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to make an assumption you are using Apache. You should probably check the `ErrorLog` of your HTTP server first. Try running:

```
tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log
```

...and then refreshing whichever page is coming back blank in your browser. If that file does not exist, I would look through your vhost files for the `ErrorLog` definition & see what file that points to.